# Query mongo ISODate using play reactive mongo

Tags: mongodb, play-reactivemongo

I am trying to query dates in mongodb.

The dates are stored as `ISODate("2015-10-08T05:48:55.778+0000")`.

Now how should i do query like `$gte` or `$lte`.

I have been using Play plugin for **reactive mongo**

To query from the mongo shell, I would need to query with=>

`{"endDateTime":{"$eq": new Date("2017-10-08T05:48:55.778+0000")}`

OR,

`{"endDateTime":{"$eq": ISODate("2017-10-08T05:48:55.778+0000")}`

So, what should I do to query it using play reactive mongo. I have been using JodaTime. I am generating the Json Object of the query, and feeding to the `find()` api straightaway.

*Yes there a lot suggestion in SO, about the topic, but none of them seem to help me in this case. I could give more info if needed.

Update Answer:

Seems like I had some confusion, when converting the dates.

When I tried converting the String Date to `Joda DateTime` , the result   when I print it in console, it would be shown as `timestamp`,but when I sent it to reactive mongo `find` it would convert to some form of string date `"2015-10-08T05:48:55.778+0000"`.

So, I had to retrieve the millisecond conversion and send it to the respective api, and mongo would process without any issues.

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/bson/typeclasses.html#provided-handlers), you can see that date/time is supported as `java.util.Date`.